# Exception on starting Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I have a web application that applies JPA, Hibernate, Spring and Wicket. When I run Tomcat, it is started, but there is an Exception:

```
WARN   org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.InputStreamZippedJarVisitor - Unable to find file      (ignored): jndi:/localhost/tracking/
java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:298)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1007)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.InputStreamZippedJarVisitor.doProcessElements(InputStreamZippedJarVisitor.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.getMatchingEntries(AbstractJarVisitor.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:614)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:131)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)...
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<!-- language: xml -->

    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
      version="1.0">
      <persistence-unit name="tracking" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.eds.eai.tracking.web.model.Archive</class>
        <class>com.eds.eai.tracking.web.model.Audit</class>
        <class>com.eds.eai.tracking.web.model.Message</class>
        <class>com.eds.eai.tracking.web.model.Partner</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"
                value="update" />
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

and this is the applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="wicketApplication"
        class="com.eds.eai.tracking.web.Application">
    </bean>

    <!-- Using a username of logging creates the tables in a schema of the same name -->
    <!-- Note the embedded driver defaults the schema to app unless a username is given -->
    <bean id="db2DataSourceDev"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:db2://gotx72.got.skf.se:50000/GOT20" />
        <property name="username" value="capsusr1" />
        <property name="password" value="welcome3" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="db2DataSourceStaging"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:db2://gotx75.got.skf.se:50000/GOT20" />
        <property name="username" value="capsusr1" />
        <property name="password" value="welcome3" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="db2DataSourceMof"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:db2://ruex12.rue.skf.net:60000/RUE11" />
        <property name="username" value="eai12" />
        <property name="password" value="welcome3" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="db2DataSourceStagingLinux"  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"  destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2://x0015.rue.skf.net:50001/RUE22" />
        <property name="username" value="capsusr1" />
        <property name="password" value="Finogaratu93" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory1"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="db2DataSourceDev" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
            value="META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory2"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="db2DataSourceStaging" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
            value="META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory3"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="db2DataSourceMof" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
            value="META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory4"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="db2DataSourceStagingLinux" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
            value="META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory"
            ref="entityManagerFactory1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- bean post-processor for JPA annotations -->
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="auditDAO"
        class="com.eds.eai.tracking.web.dao.impl.AuditDAOImpl" />   

    <bean id="configurationDAO"
        class="com.eds.eai.tracking.web.dao.impl.ConfigurationDAOImpl">
        <property name="filename" value="WEB-INF/config.xml" />
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: See if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190518/equinox-osgi-and-jpa-hibernate-finding-entities) sheds any light. Does it work despite the exception? Are you using Spring DM or OSGI?

Comment: Yes, it works despite the exception, and I'm using Spring

Comment: Anything relating to spring dm or osgi?

Comment: For more information applicationContext.xml was added.

Comment: Did you resolved your problem?